# A/B Testing in Time Series - i.i.d.?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, ab-test

If you're using the difference in differences method to run an A/B test on two time series (lets say the outcome measure is clickthrough rate), is there an i.i.d. assumption?

More specifically, if user_50 is in the dataset 20 times, can all of those observations be used, or should the within subject correlation be eliminated?

I've seen some literature vaguely say that aggregating data into a time series removes clustering bias, and I'm not sure if that clustering bias is referring to things like within subject correlation.

Answer (score 2):

I.I.D.-assumption (independent and identically distributed variables) is mentioned as one of the assumptions for difference-in-differences method (D.I.D) - and OLS. However it is considered an *additional* assumption, e.g. sometimes it is used and sometimes it is not.

*if user_50 is in the dataset 20 times, can all of those observations be used, or should the within subject correlation be eliminated?*

I am not sure if there is a universal answer to this. You could try to compare the two approaches: perform D.I.D. with all of the data (e.g. all occurrences of user_50), and with eliminated within-subject correlation. Than you would see if 
    (**1**) parallel trend assumption is valid for both approaches - which is the main assumption for D.I.D.  and 
    (**2**) see if your end result and conclusions are dependent on within-subject correlation.